# How to download full website or web pages through URL?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, web

I have to work on an application like Website Downloader which should allow user to download full website (all the files of the website) to specified location on the disk through its URL. Currently I am just able to get only html of Home Page using WebRequest and WebResponse classes. I have tried another solution using

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient ();
Client.DownloadFile("http://www.techprism.net/Default.aspx", "D:\\Downloader\\Default.aspx");
```

But here I have to place file with same name on physical location as to be downloaded and I am also unable to download CSS and JS being using on the page. I also want to allow my applicaiton to include built in browser in order to browse downloaded file in offline mode.

Please help me in this regard. Thanks in advance for your kind guidance.

Comment: You're going to have to do more work than that -- websites don't automatically tell you all the files to download, you will have to crawl through and identify them all.  Or (as noted) use a tool like wget that already does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't WGet http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/ do everything required. Just put a wrapper around that

I'm sure you can probably do everything with .Net. However I have used WGet with great success for downloading whole websites.

Comment: I have gone through WGet and came to know that wget is a command line utility. But I didn't get any idea from anywhere that how can we implement it with .net ?

Comment: Just call the command line utility from .Net and pass the required parameters to it - that will get you the website stored locally. Then you just need to implement a basic web browser control and point at the downloaded site

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply Graeme. You have used WGet with .net for downloading websites ?

Comment: Yup - however that maybe because I was familiar with it from my Perl days.